# Finding a reidue at essential singularity $z_0=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm asked to find the residue at $z_0=0$ of the following functions:

A) $f(z)=\frac{sin(z^2)}{z^2}$

B) $f(z)=z^3sin(1/z)$

I find it fairly simple to expand these using a power series but I don't obtain a $1/z$ term for any of them. Can someone please confirm that the residue of these two functions will be $0$?

Comment: The residue is the coefficient of the $z^{-1}$ term.  If that is $0$, then the residue is $0$.

Comment: That damn $z^2$ spoils all the fun!

Comment: lol @1950RobertLewis yes I feel the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part A):

$$f(z) = \frac{\sin (z^2)}{z^2}$$

is an even function, hence all coefficients of odd powers of $z$ in its Laurent expansion are $0$, in particular $\operatorname{Res}(f;0) = 0$ here. (Furthermore, this is an entire function, it has a removable singularity in $0$.)

Part B) (After the correction of the function):

$$f(z) = z^3\sin \frac{1}{z}$$

is even too, hence the residue is $0$.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me on part A. I forgot that if you have a function in terms of $\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$ and they have the same order, this implies a removable singularity. For part B, You say that odd functions "can" have a nonzero residue in 0. If that's the case, why doesn't the expansion yield a $1/z$ term?

Comment: Look again, the expansion _does_ contain a $z^{-1}$ term.

Comment: shoot, Daniel! I made a typo. It's suppose to be $z^3sin(1/z)$

Comment: In that case: even function.

Comment: Then now we have a zero residue, right?

Comment: Yes, even functions always have residue $0$ in $0$.